# Complete misunderstanding of Lie groups and representations

Tags: matrices, representation-theory, lie-groups, direct-sum

Consider a particular representation of $\operatorname{SO}(2,\mathbb{R})$:
\begin{equation}
 \begin{pmatrix}
  \operatorname{cos}(\theta) & \operatorname{sin}(\theta) \\ -\operatorname{sin}(\theta) & \operatorname{cos}(\theta)
 \end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation}

We may construct new representations of a group by direct summing old ones. Consider the matrices

\begin{equation}
\bigoplus_{j=1}^n \begin{pmatrix}
  \operatorname{cos}(\theta) & \operatorname{sin}(\theta) \\ -\operatorname{sin}(\theta) & \operatorname{cos}(\theta)
 \end{pmatrix},
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\bigoplus_{j=1}^n \begin{pmatrix}
  \operatorname{cos}(\theta_j) & \operatorname{sin}(\theta_j) \\ -\operatorname{sin}(\theta_j) & \operatorname{cos}(\theta_j)
 \end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation}

Do the examples provide a representation for any of these groups: $\operatorname{SO}(2,\mathbb{R})$, $\operatorname{SO}(2n,\mathbb{R})$, $\bigoplus_j^n \operatorname{SO}(2,\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: What do you mean by the direct sum of matrices?

Comment: @DanielMcLaury. Hello. By direct sum I mean placing them as the blocks in a block diagonal matrix. In terms of the notation above I have one direct sum where all the angles are the same in all the blocks and another where the angles may differ between blocks. Does that answer your question?

Comment: What you have described are not representations in the sense of representation theory.  A representation of a group, in the sense of representation theory is an action of that group on a vector space.  What you have described is a "way of realizing $\operatorname{SO}_2(\mathbb R)$" not a representation of $\operatorname{SO}_2(\mathbb R)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be clear that the direct sum of two representations $V$ and $W$ of a group $G$ gives a representation of $G$ on $V \oplus W$ by $g \cdot (v, w) = (g \cdot v, g \cdot w)$.  Note that the matrix of $g$ on $V \oplus W$ is block diagonal, with the matrix of $g$ on $V$ in the upper-left-hand corner and the matrix of $g$ on $W$ in the lower-right-hand corner.

For the other questions, note that to specify a representation of a group it's not enough to list some matrices; you have to specify which group element corresponds to which matrix.

Comment: I think my confusion is just that I relate representations to matrices too much and I forget the space upon which they act. Your answer helped to clarify my confusion, thank you.