# What is the Lie group that leaves this matrix invariant?

Tags: group-theory, matrices, lie-groups, direct-sum, matrix-congruences

What is the group that leaves 
\begin{equation}
Y = \bigoplus_{j=1}^{k} \alpha_j \mathbb{I}_{2n_j\times 2n_j}
\end{equation}
 invariant under congruence ($Y = XYX^T$) where $\alpha_j \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\alpha_j \neq 0$?

I have toyed with different variations of the special orthogonal group; my misunderstandings of how matrix groups relate to representations are fleshed out [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1283508/complete-misunderstanding-of-lie-groups-and-representations).

Comment: If  all $\alpha_i \neq 0,$ then you have $O(p,q)$ (indefinite orthogonal group) for some value of $p,q.$

Comment: Ah!! I had forgotten the definition of that group, thank you. Does variation in the $\alpha$s not mess with the standard $\operatorname{diag}(1,\ldots,1,-1,\ldots,-1)$ definition?

Comment: No.  The signature is invariant (Sylvester's Law Of Intertia).  You can first scale all $\alpha_i$ to have magnitude 1 via a transformation $Y_1=B^T Y B.$   Then you can permute $Y_2 =P^T Y_1 P.$    Then $Y_2$ has the 1's and -1's separated accordingly.

Comment: @mattbiesecker, thank you very much, that is incredibly helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Answer from Matt Biesecker in comments*. *Sylvester's Law taken from [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia)*.

**Sylvester's Law of Inertia**:

Given some non-singular real symmetric matrix $A$, the group of matrices that satisfy
\begin{equation}
 XAX^T = A.
\end{equation}
is $\operatorname{O}(p,q)$ where $p$ and $q$ are the number of postive and negative eigenvalues of $A$ respectively.

**Proof**:

Real symmetric matrices can be diagonalised by congruence by an orthogonal matrix, so we know that there exists $Q$ such that
\begin{equation}
A = QEQ^T
\end{equation}
where $E$ is the diagonal matrix of eigenvalues. Given $W$ such that $W_{ii} = (\sqrt{|E_{ii}|})^{-1}$ we obtain 
\begin{equation}
E = WDW^T
\end{equation}
where $D$ is a diagonal matrix of $1$s and $-1$s. Thus
\begin{equation}
 XAX^T = (XQW)D(XQW)^T = (QW)D(QW)^T.
\end{equation}
and so
\begin{equation}
 \left((QW)^{-1}X(QW)\right)D\left((QW)^{-1}X(QW)\right)^T = D.
\end{equation}
The group that preserves $D$ under congruence is $\operatorname{O}(p,q)$ by definition. Thus the group of $X$ matrices is isomorphic to $\operatorname{O}(p,q)$.

**Relation to question**:

$Y$ is a nonsingular real symmetrix matrix.